# How to exit python deamon thread gracefully

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

I have code like below

```py
def run():
  While True:
    doSomething()
def main():
  thread = threading.thread(target = run)
  thread.setDaemon(True)
  thread.start() 
  doSomethingElse()
```

if I Write code like above, when the main thread exits, the Deamon thread will exit, but maybe still in the process of `doSomething`.

The main function will be called outside, I am not allowed to use `join` in the main thread,
is there any way I can do to make the Daemon thread exit gracefully upon the main thread completion.

Comment: Note that the entire point of `daemon` threads is that they *do not* exit gracefully. Is your goal actually "how to gracefully exit a ``daemon`` thread", or is it "how to gracefully exit a Thread running a loop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use thread `threading.Event` to signal child thread when to exit from main thread.

Example:

```
class DemonThead(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.shutdown_flag = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.shutdown_flag:
            # Run your code here
            pass

def main_thread():
    demon_thread = DemonThead()
    demon_thread.setDaemon(True) 
    demon_thread.start()
    
    # Stop your thread
    demon_thread.shutdown_flag.set()
    demon_thread.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to use `join`, but you can set an `Event` and do not use `daemonic` flag. Official doc is below:

> **Note**: Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.